# What cryptography solution can I use in an offline scenario for an xml file?

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, obfuscation

Our application has an xml file that contains information for the application to work properly. This file is generated by our web api server and sent to the client application. The client application needs to be able to read from this file, but we don't want our users to see or modify it. This file exists in their file system for a period of time while they will need to read from it. In this scenario, they are disconnected from the internet or network. We can of course encrypt it on our server before we send it, but the question remains about decryption.

If I use a public/private key method, this is sort of a pointless effort because I have to store the private key somewhere with the client. My other question, is in this way, why would I need to store the public key on the server? (especially if this file is generated every so often with a new private/public key pair when the file is requested from the server again).

I could use a symmetric algorithm, but again I have to store something with the client.

I also thought about just generating a hash for the file, but again I would have to store the salt with the client to compute the same hash and compare if the file has been tampered with (thus not offering encryption, but at least a way to know it has been modified).

At the end of the day I'm looking for a solution that just keeps our users from 
 seeing the blatantly obvious.

I've gone through all the XMLEncryption stuff on Msdn and SO articles, these all require key management of some kind, but are there other solutions for this scenario? Or am I stuck storing a private key with the client so they can decrypt the file?

Comment: Your problem falls into the very broad category of digital rights management, and inherits all of DRMs problems. In short, there are no solutions that are good. The solution I usually see is to lightly obfuscate the file, perhaps encrypting it with a hard-coded key. There are endless variations on this theme depending on how much effort you want to put in it. All of it can be overcome by a determined adversary. In the end it is not the cryptography that is protecting you, it is the amount of reverse-engineering that is required to find the key.

Comment: What level of security do you need? Is it enough to obfuscate it a bit, by zipping the file? If you need high-level security, maybe it is worth it to manage the keys. Encryption is also possible without the overhead of a key store. Take a look at **BouncyCastle**

Comment: Enough security to prevent plain-text modification to the file, and preferably to non-readable by a human. Understandably any solution can be cracked/hacked/gone around, but we're not trying to really go to that extent, but at least be able to manage our software honestly. It sounds like based on @jameskpolk, I agree, it is a type of DRM, that at least using one of these algorithms solves both problems, though it is not a secure solution, it is secure enough for what we are after.

Comment: Seriously, you should consider https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You may still *sign* the message, which would allow to check if the file hasn't been modified (see XMLSig). But at the end - as already commented, it depends how hard you will make for the users to replace the key.

Comment: @bradbury9 I think you are right that it might be better - is there a way a moderator could move this there? This isn't exactly a programming question specifically for C# per se. Thanks for the feedback guys!

Comment: You can digitally sign the XML with a private key managed by the server and verify it  with a public key/certificate embeded in your app. This check would detect any type of alteration. Of course, an user could decompile your application an change the key, but if this happens, he could also eliminate any kind of security control. As the rest of the people have said, in the end it's about how much effort you want to invest

Comment: *"... is there a way a moderator could move this [to InfoSec.SE]"* - You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)